# Objective-C completion call never completing

Tags: ios, objective-c, completionhandler

I'm trying to send an instance inside a blocking call and waiting for it finish so I can use the value later on in my program but the completion function never finishes.  I'm extremely new to Objective-C and I'm only using objective-c as a wrapper and I can't figure out why my completion calls never finish.

```
[sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
    if (token == nil || error != nil) {
        tokenChar = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
    }
    else{
        tokenChar = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
    }
}];
while(tokenChar == nil){
}
return tokenChar;
```

So now I've changed my method to this

```
void StripeWrapper::retrieveToken:(id)(char* myKey, char* cardNumber, int expMonth, int expYear, char* cvc) completion:(void (^)(NSString *))completion {
    NSString* NScardNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cardNumber];
    NSString* NScvc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cvc];

    STPCardParams *cardParams = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];
    cardParams.number = NScardNumber;
    cardParams.expMonth = expMonth;
    cardParams.expYear = expYear;
    cardParams.cvc = NScvc;

    NSString *myPublishableKey = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myKey];
    STPAPIClient *sharedClient = [[STPAPIClient alloc] initWithPublishableKey:myPublishableKey];

    [sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
        NSString *tokenChar;
        if (token == nil || error != nil) {
            tokenChar = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
        } else {
            tokenChar = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
        }
        if (completion) completion(tokenChar);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use the value in the  completion block . You will be blocking the main thread which will make your a unresponsive.

Comment: there are 2 ways I can think of in handling this scenario. 1) dispatch group wait. 2) make a function that handles the callback and from your createTOkenWithCard method call the completion of that entire function.

Comment: To determine why the completion is never called we need the code of `createTokenWithCard`, because that's who is responsible for calling the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I handled objective-c, so pardon me if I make some syntax mistake.

```
// This just uses completion block and will call the completion once the createTokenWithCard function finishes its execution
- (void) someFunctionName: (void (^)(NSString * theThingIWant, NSError *error)) completion { 

         [sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
                      if (token == nil || error != nil) {
                           tokenChar = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
                       } else{
                              tokenChar = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
                      }
                     completion(tokenChar, error)
          }];   
}
// And in your caller its like
   [self someFunctionName:^(NSString *some, NSError *error) {
         // do the thing you want here
   }];



// Second approach will be dispatches. This will wait for createTokenWithCard before it returns
 - (void) someFunctionName: (id) cardParams { 
         __block NSString * theThingYouNeed;
         dispatch_group_t someGroupName = dispatch_group_create();

         [sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
                      if (token == nil || error != nil) {
                           theThingYouNeed = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
                       } else{
                              theThingYouNeed = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
                      }
                     dispatch_group_leave(someGroupName);
          }];

        // this will wait forever so try to have a timeout I guess.
        dispatch_group_wait(someGroupName,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        return theThingYouNeed
}
```

Comment: I see we answered about the same at about the same time.  I'll leave mine since it's distinct in a couple ways: (a) the OP overloads the tokenChar with the error in the case of the error, (b) i add NSNotification as an alternative.  (KVO is an alternative, too).

Comment: Minor point, someFunctionName needs to declare `cardParams` and `tokenChar` to compile.

Comment: yea never thought of notification and it still a good alternative I think and good point on the card param, never noticed it lol

Answer (score 0):

Async methods have a way of proliferating, often forcing their callers to be async, too.  In other words, if the result of methodA depends on methodB, and methodB is async, then so must be methodA.

So the method that contains the OP code probably ought to be declared like this:

```
- (void)getMyTokenChar:(id)someParams completion:(void (^)(NSString *))completion {
    // form cardParams with someParams (or maybe they are the same
    [sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
        NSString *tokenChar;
        if (token == nil || error != nil) {
            tokenChar = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
        } else {
            tokenChar = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
        }
        if (completion) completion(tokenChar);
    }];
}
```

The caller would do this...

```
[theTokenCharObject getMyTokenChar:@"someParams" completion:^(NSString *tokenChar) {
    // tokenChar will be a string or an error description here
}];
```

Here's the bad news, the method containing that calling code will probably need to be async, too.  Does it never end?

Yes, it ends, usually at the UI...

```
// do something to the UI to say the app is busy, like an activity indicator view
[theTokenCharObject getMyTokenChar:@"someParams" completion:^(NSString *tokenChar) {
    // remove the activity indicator view
    // show something new to the user: "we got the thing that depends on tokenChar!!"
}];
```

There are a couple alternatives, the simplest to describe uses NSNotificationCenter.  Your original method get's to be (seem) synchronous...

```
- (void)getMyTokenChar:(id)someParams {
    // form cardParams with someParams (or maybe they are the same
    [sharedClient createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token,NSError *error) {
        NSString *tokenChar;
        if (token == nil || error != nil) {
            tokenChar = [error.localizedDescription UTF8String];
        } else {
            tokenChar = [token.tokenId UTF8String];
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TokenGetterDidGetToken" object:tokenChar];
    }];
}
```

Any other part of your app subscribes like this...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didGetToken:) name:@"TokenGetterDidGetToken" object:nil];
```

and must implement the selector...

```
- (void)didGetToken:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // notification.object will be the tokenChar
}
```

Generally, though, you'll be better off passing blocks around.  Take the UI example I gave.  One part of the code will change the UI to be busy, another disconnected part will have to change it back.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  Sorry I'm completely new and obj-c looks so much different than c++ and java.  Is this how my formatting should look? (See above)

Comment: I think might be running into problems because I'm running this wrapper through cython.  I fell like I'm going to be doing endless completion blocks.  Will the last completion block be enough if I call it through cython?

Comment: The formatting is a matter of taste.  Mine is generally accepted (though a little idiosyncratic in places, e.g. many authors say `SomeClass*`, and I say `SomeClass *`).  I've never used cython, but it depends if the python caller needs the result of the async method returned to it.  If it does, then the whole chain needs to be async.